# Segmentation fault(core dumped) doesn't show in gdb

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, backtracking, att

I tried turning some C++ code into assembly. The program uses an iterative backtracking algorithm to find permutations of an array, and picks the first one that satisfies some conditions.

The C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int m,c;
int x=0;
bool verify(vector<int> v, int m){
    for(int i = 1;i<=c;i++){
        int found=0;
        int cnt=0;
        for(int j=0;j<v.size();j++){
            if(found==1){
                cnt++;
                if(v[j]==i){
                    if(cnt<=m)
                        return false;
                    cnt=0;
                }
            }
            if(v[j]==i){
                found=1;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

void permutations(vector<int> s,int m, vector<int> v,vector<int> zeros)
{
    int n = s.size();
 
    if (n == 0) {
        return;
    }
 
    if(n==1){
        return;
    }

    while (1)
    {
        int j = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
            if(v[i]==0){
                v[i]=s[j];
                j++;
            }
        }
        if(verify(v,m)){
            for(int i = 0; i<v.size();i++){
                cout<<v[i]<<' ';
            }
            x=1;
            return;
        }        
        else{
            for(int i = 0; i<zeros.size();i++){
                v[zeros[i]]=0;
            }
        }
        
        int i = n - 1;
        while (s[i-1] >= s[i])
        {
            if (--i == 0) {
                return;
            }
        }
 
        j = n - 1;
        while (j > i && s[j] <= s[i - 1]) {
            j--;
        }
 
        swap(s[i - 1], s[j]);
 
        reverse (s.begin() + i, s.end());
    }
}
 
int main()
{
    cin>>c>>m;
    vector<int> v(3*c);
    for(int i = 0;i<3*c;i++)
        cin>>v[i];
    int j =0;
    vector<int> str(3*c);
    for(int i = 1;i<=c;i++){
        str[j]=i;
        j++;
        str[j]=i;
        j++;
        str[j]=i;
        j++;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<3*c;i++){
        if(v[i]!=0){
            for(int k = 0;k<3*c;k++){
                if(str[k]==v[i]){
                    str.erase(str.begin()+k);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    vector<int> zeros(0);
    j=0;
    for(int i=0;i<3*c;i++){
        if(v[i]==0){
            zeros.push_back(i);
            j++;
        }
    }
    
    permutations(str,m,v,zeros);
    if(x==0)cout<<-1;
    
    return 0;
}
```

When i try running the asm code with the input `5 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 5` i get Segmentation fault(core dumped), but when i debug the code with gdb the program finishes succesfully, and i have no idea where to even start looking.

```
.data
    c: .long 0
    zeros: .space 400
    x: .long 0
    sir: .space 400
    n: .long 0
    m: .long 0
    v: .space 400
    delim: .asciz " "
    formatScanf: .asciz "%400[^\n]"
    length: .long 0
    sirlength: .long 0
    j: .long 0
    str: .space 400
    zero: .long 0
    l: .space 4
    d: .space 4
    check: .long 0
    formatPrintf: .asciz "%d "
    jnk: .long 0
    final: .asciz "\n"
    formatPrintf2: .asciz "%c"
.text


verify:
    pushl %ebx
    pushl %esp
    pushl %ebp
    pushl %esi
    pushl %edi

    movl $3, %eax
    movl %esp, %esi
    mul %esi
    movl %esi, %eax 
    movl $0, %ecx
    movl $-1, %ebx
    
    jmp for
    
for:
    add $1, %ecx
    cmp %ecx, %esp
    jl return_verify_true
    
    movl $0, -24(%esp)
    movl $0, -28(%esp)
    movl $-1, %ebx
    jmp for_for
for_for:
    add $1, %ebx
    cmp %ebx, %ebp
    je for

    cmp $1, -24(%esp)
    je found
    jmp not_found
    
found:
    add $1, -28(%esp)
    cmp (%edi, %ebx, 4), %ecx
    je adevarat
    
    jmp not_found
    
not_found:
    cmp (%edi, %ebx, 4), %ecx
    je add1
    
    jmp for_for
    
adevarat:
    movl -28(%esp), %edx
    cmp %edx, 12(%esp)
    jl return_verify_false
    
    movl $0, -24(%esp)
    
    jmp for_for

return_verify_true:
    popl jnk
    popl jnk
    
    popl %edi
    popl %esp
    popl %ebp
    popl %esi
    popl %edi
    
    add $20,  %esp
    movl $1, %eax
    jmp final_permutations
    
return_verify_false:
    popl jnk
    popl jnk
    
    popl %edi
    popl %esp
    popl %ebp
    popl %esi
    popl %edi
    
    movl $0, %eax
    
    jmp while1

add1:
    add $1, -24(%esp)
    jmp for_for


permutations:
    
    pushl %ebx
    pushl %esp
    pushl %ebp
    pushl %esi
    pushl %edi
    
    lea v, %edi
    lea str, %esi
    lea zeros, %edx
    
    sub $20, %esp
        
    cmp $0, 4(%esp)
    je return
    
    cmp $1, 4(%esp)
    je numaru1
    
    jmp while1
    
numaru1:
    movl %esi, %ecx
    movl %ecx, (%edi, %edx,4)

    
    call verify

while1:
    movl $0, %ebx
    movl $-1, %ecx  
    
for_in_while:
    add $1, %ecx
    cmp %ecx, %ebp
    jl for_in_while_exit
    
    cmp $0, (%edi, %ecx, 4)
    je este_zero
    
    jmp for_in_while
    
este_zero:
    movl (%esi, %ebx, 4), %eax
    movl %eax, (%edi, %ebx, 4)
    add $1, %ebx
    jmp for_in_while

for_in_while_exit:
    
    movl $-1, %ebx
    
    call verify
    cmp $1, %eax
    je crazy

    jmp not_crazy   
crazy:
    add $1, %ebx
    cmp %ebx, %ebp
    jge crazy_exit
    
    pushl $formatPrintf
    pushl (%edi, %ebx, 4)
    call printf
    popl %edx
    popl %edx
    
    jmp crazy
    
    movl $1, check
    ret
    
not_crazy:
    add $1, %ebx
    cmp %ebx, 4(%esp)
    jge crazy_exit
    
    movl (%edx, %ebx, 4), %eax
    movl $0, (%edi, %eax, 4)
    
    jmp not_crazy
    
crazy_exit:
    movl %esp, %eax
    sub $1, %eax
    movl %eax, %ebx
    sub $1, %ebx
    
while2:
    
    movl (%esi, %ebx, 4), %ecx
    cmp %ecx, (%esi, %eax, 4)
    jl while2_exit
    
    sub $1, %ebx
    sub $1, %eax
    
    cmp $0,%ebx
    je return
    
    jmp while2  
    
while2_exit:
    
    movl %esp, %ecx
    sub $1, %ecx
    movl %eax, jnk

while3:
    
    cmp %ecx, %eax
    jg break
    movl (%esi, %ecx, 4), %eax
    cmp %eax, (%esi, %ebx, 4)
    jl break
    
    sub $1, %ecx
    
    jmp while3
    
break:
    movl jnk, %eax
    sub $1, %eax
    
    movl (%esi, %eax, 4), %edx
    movl %ecx, (%esi, %eax, 4)
    movl %edx, %ecx
    
    add $1, %eax
    lea str, %edi
    movl 4(%esp), %ebx
    
reverse:
    cmp %eax, 4(%esp)
    je while1
    
    movl (%esi, %eax, 4), %edx
    movl (%edi, %ebx, 4), %ecx
    movl %ecx, (%esi, %eax, 4)
    movl %edx, (%edi, %ebx, 4)
    
    jmp reverse
    
return:
    popl jnk
    popl jnk
    
    popl %edi
    popl %esp
    popl %ebp
    popl %esi
    popl %edi
    
    add $20,  %esp
    jmp final_permutations

    
    
.global main

main:

    pushl $sir
    pushl $formatScanf
    call scanf
    popl %ebx
    popl %ebx
    
    pushl $sir
    call strlen
    popl %ebx

    movl %eax, sirlength    
    movl %eax, length
    
    pushl $delim
    pushl $sir
    call strtok
    popl %ebx
    popl %ebx
    
    sub $48, %eax
    
    movl %eax, n
    
    pushl $delim
    pushl $0
    call strtok
    popl %ebx
    popl %ebx
    
    sub $48, %eax
    
    movl %eax, m
    
    movl $0, %ecx
    lea v, %edi
    
et_for:

    pushl $delim
    pushl $0
    call strtok
    popl %ebx
    popl %ebx
    
    sub $48, %eax
    
    movl %eax, (%edi, %ecx, 4)
    
    add $1, %ecx
    
    cmp %ecx, length
    jg et_for
    
    movl $1, %eax
    lea str, %edi
    movl $0, %ecx
        
et_for2:
    
    movl %eax, (%edi, %ecx, 4)
    add $1, %ecx
    
    movl %eax, (%edi, %ecx, 4)
    add $1, %ecx
    
    movl %eax, (%edi, %ecx, 4)
    add $1, %ecx
    
    add $1, %eax
    
    cmp %eax, n
    jg et_for2

    
    movl $0, %ecx
    lea v, %edi
    movl $0, %esi

    movl $0, %eax
    movl $0, %ebx
    movl $0, j
    movl %ebp, x
    lea sir, %ebp
    movl %esp, d
et_for3:
    movl (%edi, %esi, 4), %esp
    movl %esp, zero
    cmp $0, zero
    jne et_for4
    
    jmp et_for3
    
et_for4:
    movl (%edi, %esi, 4), %edx
    cmp (%ebp, %ebx, 4), %edx
    je erase
    
    cmp %eax, length
    jl et_for3

erase:
    add $1, j
    movl j, %edx
    sub $1, j
    
    
    movl (%ebp, %edx, 4), %esi
    movl j, %esi
    
    sub $1, sirlength
    
    add $1, j
    movl length, %esi
    sub $1, %esi
    cmp j, %esi
    jg et_for3

    movl $0, j
    movl $0, %ecx
    
    lea zeros, %esi 
    
et_for5:
    cmp $0, (%edi, %ecx, 4)
    je egal
    
    add $1, %ecx
    
    cmp length, %ecx
    jl et_for5
    
    jmp dupa_egal

egal:
    movl %ecx, (%esi, %ecx, 4)
    add $1, %ecx
    jmp et_for5

dupa_egal:
    
    movl x, %ebp
    movl d, %esp
    pushl length
    pushl m
    pushl sirlength
    pushl n
    call permutations
final_permutations: 
    popl %ebx
    popl %ebx
    popl %ebx
    popl %ebx
    
    cmp $0, check
    je finalfinal
    
et_exit:
    
    pushl $final
    pushl $formatPrintf2
    call printf
    popl %ebx
    popl %ebx

    mov $1, %eax
    mov $0, %ebx
    int $0x80
    
finalfinal:

    pushl $-1
    pushl $formatPrintf
    call printf
    popl %ebx
    popl %ebx
    jmp et_exit
```

Comment: That's a lot of code.  I don't suppose you can reproduce the heisenbug with a smaller [mcve]?  Your code has some instructions like `cmp $1, -24(%esp)` where modern GAS warns `no instruction mnemonic suffix given and no register operands; using default for 'cmp'`.  (The default is 32-bit operand-size; if those were supposed to be byte compares / adds then that's a bug.  If 32-bit was intended, then it's bad style.  Use `cmpl` or `addl` with immediate-to-memory, just like you're doing for `movl`.)

Comment: When I built it with `gcc -m32 -no-pie foo.s`, and ran in GDB with that input string, it does segfault at 9410 in `et_for2`.  That's `0x8049410 <et_for2>     mov    %eax,(%edi,%ecx,4)`, the top of `et_for2`.  I used `-no-pie` since without that option, ld warned about making a relocation in the read-only `.text` section, `creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE`.

Comment: Possible reasons for happening to work under GDB are: different stack layout, e.g. more env vars, if you were accessing stuff there.  Different ASLR (GDB disables ASLR by default), although that's less likely since things will still be multiple pages apart.

Answer (score 2):

> i have no idea where to even start looking

GDB is capable of post-mortem debugging.

*All* you have to do is look at the `core` dump (produced by running the program outside of GDB), like so:

```
gdb /path/to/executable /path/to/core
(gdb) where
```

Comment by Peter Cordes explains some of the reasons why program may run "fine" under GDB but crash outside of GDB, or vice versa.